# Looping through data frame and adding each value in column to PDF

Tags: r, sweave

Please bare with me as im UBBER new to creating pdfs in R Studio. My R code grabs a bunch of files from an ftp site and for each of these files I loop through and create a pdf...all this works great. Within this r code it creates a dataframe with two columns code and URL. For each pdf I would like to take each url and include it between text. Each pdf run may have different number of rows in the dataframe. I have not found anything giving me info on a for loop in sweave. I am having to use sweave as Markdown wont work on my companies systems (don't ask!).

Here is my rnw file so far.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,hyperref,Sweave,fancyvrb}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm}
\title{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{/home/siobhan/CyberHealthCheck/header_cut.png}
\end{center}
<<echo=FALSE>>=
urls<-nrow(dfCodes)
@
\fbox {
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
    \large
    \textbf{About you}
    \\
    \small
    \Sexpr{company_name}
    \\
    \Sexpr{rank_text}
    }
}
\\
\\
\fbox {
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
    \small
    There were \Sexpr{urls} vunerabilities found. 
    \\
    \\
    \href{\Sexpr{dfCodes[1,2]}}{here} and
    \href{\Sexpr{dfCodes[2,2]}}{here} 
    }
}
\begin{center}
<<do-my-job, echo=FALSE>>=
options(width=60)
library(knitr)
knitr::kable(head(dfCodes))
@
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{/home/siobhan/CyberHealthCheck/footer_lg.png}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Secondly, can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ive worked out the majority of the problem, easy really. New chunk with the following code...now just to work out how to mix text and chunk.

```
<<test, echo=FALSE>>=
for (i in 1:nrow(dfCodes)) 
{
cat(paste(dfCodes[i,2],"\n"))
}
@
```